# Facebook PHP SDK chat API returns error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-chat

I am developing my facebook platform application which uses facebook chat API. I tried to use the example code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/. It returns error. I tried to understand where exactly I get the error and I found out that this part of the code returns false.

```
if (!find_xmpp($fp,  'MECHANISM', 'X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM')) {
return false;
}
```

In addition I have an xmpp_login extanded  permission.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested I found the solution.
In the example provided by facebook all the `<` and `>` tags are represented as an html chars like `&gt;` and `&lt;` they must be changed to normal tags like `<auth>` etc.